# Z3: Extract array interpretation

Tags: c, arrays, z3

How is it possible to extract the function interpretation of an array in Z3 using the C API? When I query Rise4Fun with, say, the following instance:

```
(declare-fun arr () (Array Int Int))
(assert (= 5 (select arr 3)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(exit)
```

, I get:

```
sat 
(model 
    (define-fun arr () (Array Int Int) (_ as-array k!0))
    (define-fun k!0 ((x!1 Int)) Int (ite (= x!1 3) 5 5))
)
```

Is it possible to extract the function interpretation of `k!0` using the C API only? I've tried applying `Z3_model_get_func_interp` on the array constant declaration, and also on the term that is returned for the array in the SAT model, but always get an `Error: invalid argument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. A very similar question has been asked recently and the answer with examples can be found here: [Read func interp of a z3 array from the z3 model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885457/read-func-interp-of-a-z3-array-from-the-z3-model/22918197#22918197)